# AngularJs: Disabled submit button is gets enable from firebug console

Tags: validation, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using ng:Disabled directive for disabling my submit button. Its working fine its not enabling until all the required input fields are getting filled, but when I am inspecting the element using Google chrome firebug console and manually delete the disabled attribute from submit button then its get "Enabled" and form is submitted. So my question is that how to handle this type of problem. There are any option to checking validate from controller and enable/disable submit button from controller.

Please give me some suggestion for this.

Basically I am referring this url: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngDisabled

Comment: This doesn't relate to AngularJS specifically: anybody can tamper with an HTML page, or even submit a form using command line tools such as CURL outside of the browser. Validate the data also server-side to be safe.

Comment: Oh yes... but can I validate form in client side using controller.

Comment: Ensure your form doesn't have an `action` attribute, and hook up the [ng-submit](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSubmit) directive of the form element or [ng-click](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClick) directive on the first button or input field of type submit. See [form](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form) for more details. From that event handler perform any validation you might require and send the form only if validation is OK.

Comment: I'll repost the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure your form doesn't have an `action` attribute, and hook up

> the [ng-submit](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSubmit)
>   directive of the form element or the
>   [ng-click](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClick)
>   directive on the first button or input field of type submit.

See [form](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform) for more details.

From that event handler you can perform additional validations and send form only if validation is OK or show an error otherwise.

Comment: Yes @David, form has error object which has validation information which is useful for checking validation using controller. I am using below code for getting form validation information..... 
 $scope.$watch('myForm', function(){
        console.log('$scope.myForm', $scope.myForm);
    });

Comment: than, if I do this what should I check there??if the form is valid or invalid??it shows all the `ANGULARJS` objects.